# How to use geopandas.read_file() with an url to get data from a WFS server?

Tags: geopandas, wfs

I'm looking to read geodata from a WFS server. When I paste this url to my browser I think I get the data that I want but for some reason `geopandas.read_file(url)` gives me an error "not recognized as a supported file format", but if I use requests and `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features()` it works. Should I somehow specify to `read_file()` what the file format in the url is?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests

wfs_url = 'https://kartta.hel.fi/ws/geoserver/avoindata/wfs'
layer = 'avoindata:Opaskartta_alueenviiva'
params = dict(service='WFS', version="1.0.0", request='GetFeature',
      typeName=layer, outputFormat='json',startIndex=33000,count=100)
r = requests.Request('GET', wfs_url, params=params).prepare()

data = gpd.read_file(r.url)
```

throws and error

> DriverError: '/vsicurl/https://kartta.hel.fi/ws/geoserver/avoindata/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=avoindata%3AOpaskartta_alueenviiva&outputFormat=json' not recognized as a supported file format.

but this works:

```
s = requests.Session()
res = s.send(r)
data = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json(), crs={'init':'EPSG:3879'})
```

Is there a way to read the data directly from the url to geopandas?

As a side note, why doesn't the parameter `count=100` limit the response to 100 instances?

Comment: The WFS 1.0.0 GetCapabilities response doesn't report JSON as supported, so the error message seems correct.  You should be expecting only the default GML2 as a response format.  WFS version 1.0.0 doesn't support paging, and neither startindex or count are defined parameters.  To limit results you should use `maxFeatures`  If you want JSON and paging you should use WFS version 2.0.0